# Why does Cypress returns an error when extending styled components?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, styled-components

I'm working on a React components library, and I need to add component testing. For this, I'm using Cypress. Most tests work well, except tests for components that I extend later with Styled components. On these ones, I get this error:

```bash
(uncaught exception)ReferenceError: Cannot access '<Component>' before initialization
```

On the components where I extend these first ones, the tests are working. What did I do wrong?

This is my code:

First component, the one where I get the error:

```js
const StyledFlexbox = styled.div`
    ...styles
`

export function Flexbox(props) {
    return <StyledFlexbox  {...props} />
}
```

Second component, where I extend it:

```js
import { Flexbox } from "../Flexbox"

const StyledSkeletonCard = styled(Flexbox)`
   ...styles
`
```

And the test for Flexbox component:

```js
describe("<Flexbox />", () => {
    it("renders <Flexbox /> component", () => {
        cy.mount(
            <Flexbox data-testid="testid">
                Hello
            </Flexbox>
        )
        cy.get('[data-testid="testid"]').should("exist")
    })
})
```

Which returns:

```bash
(uncaught exception)ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Flexbox' before initialization
```

Also, when I use any of these components inside my app they work well, and I do not get any error. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Is it the `Flexbox` test that's failing, or the `StyledFlexbox` test? I presume the latter, since your question is about styled component. If so, would need to see the complete test for `StyledFlexbox` including imports. I'm guessing you have missed adding the `styled` library to `cy.mount()`

Comment: There's no test for the `StyledFlexbox`. They fail only if I extend the `Flexbox` component (`const StyledSkeletonCard = styled(Flexbox)`). If I replace it by `const StyledSkeletonCard = styled.div` the test for `Flexbox` work. And in both cases tests for `StyledSkeletonCard` work

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the problem - the above code works perfectly for me! Can you provide any more details to make this question reproducible?

Comment: I created a repo here https://github.com/JulSeb42/cypress-styled, with exactly the same config etc. as the full project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you created dependencies between components by sourcing `cssVariables` from `/lib/index.ts`. When you access that from the component test, all the other import/export components that are part of `lib` are initiated as well.

I haven't tried to untangle the dependencies (it's a big job), but the easy fix is to *also* source the `Flexbox` component from `/lib/index.ts`.

```js
// import { Flexbox } from "../Flexbox"            // not this import!
import { cssVariables, Flexbox } from "../../.."
```

If I were you I would try to decouple the components, see [Why Are SOLID Principles Vital...](https://www.bridge-global.com/blog/why-are-solid-principles-vital-when-designing-software-in-the-object-oriented-world/)

> Tight coupling means a group of classes are dependent on one another which should be avoided for better maintainability and readability of the code.